# Procedure to find multiples values in a table and insert if doesnt exist using pl/sql

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursor, procedure

I have this **table** with this relationship: **UNIT** --> **CHARGE** ---> **ROLE**

```
UNIT_CODE    |    CHARGE_CODE    |    ROLE_CODE
0101010001   |     9023409       |    AZAAAA
0102010002   |     8023409       |    AXAAAB
0103010003   |     7023409       |    ACAAAC
0104010004   |     6023409       |    AVAAAV
0101010001   |     5023409       |    NEWROL
0102010002   |     4023409       |    AZAAAA
```

This table has almost 2.000 rows/line.

So, here is the situations:

I have to insert a specific ROLE_COD (`NEWROL`) for a specific 90 **unit_code**. But this role apply for a specific charge of the units.

Example: i have to insert the **role_code** = `NEWROLE` for this **units** `0101010001` and this **charge** `5023409`

- So, i have to check:

  1. If units `0101010001` already exist? - YES
  2. If the **unit / charge** `0101010001 / 5023409` relationship already exist? - YES
  3. If the **unit / charge / rol** `0101010001 / 5023409 / NEWROL` already exist?  - YES

If the answer is YES for the 3 questions i have to check other **unit / charge** combinations:

`0102010002   / 4023409`

1. If **units** `0102010002` already exist? - YES
2. If the **unit / charge** `0102010002 / 4023409` relationship already exist? - YES
3. If the **unit / charge / rol** `0102010002 / 4023409 / NEWROL` already exist?  - NO

So i have to insert into the table the role: NEWROL for this units/charge and check the other units and charge.

**NOTE:** The units are unique, but some units have the same/multiples roles or charge.

I have to check 90 units, i need a procedure to take the `unit_code` and `charge` to make the validations and insert the `role_code` if necesary.

Comment: Where do the values for these ninety `unit_code` , `charge` combos come from?  Another table?

Comment: No, theyre come from the same table. But i already identified the 90 `unit_code` with theyre specific `charge` that i have to check. @APC

Comment: UNIT_CODE   isn't `unique` . `0101010001` is repeated

Comment: Youre right @MahendarMahi but in this table were gonna find the same `unit_code` with diference `code_charge` and `role_code`. This is a relationship table. So, i wanna know if i can make a procedure when i run it take the `unit_code, charge_code` and test if they have the `NEWROL` if it doesnt have insert into the `table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the situation using this query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure
    (in_unit_code IN table_1.unit_code%TYPE,
     in_charge_code IN table_1.charge_code%TYPE,
     in_role_code IN table_1.role_code%TYPE)
    AS
        BEGIN
        trace('my_procedure_p', 'a', 'Role Insert starting');
            INSERT INTO table_1 (
                unit_code,
                charge_code,
                role_code
                ) values (
               in_unit_code,
               in_charge_code,
               in_role_code
           );
           trace('my_procedure_p', 'a',
           'It is inserted correctly. ROLE: ' || in_role_code ||
           ', UNIT: ' || in_unit_code ||
           ', CHARGE: ' || in_charge_code ||
           ' Date: ' || SYSDATE);    
           COMMIT;
    --Note: If the insert is successful i COMMIT, but if records are duplicates i captured with this exception.
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
    ptraza('my_procedure_p', 'a',
    'Attention, ROLE: ' || in_role_code ||
    ' It is already in the table UNIT: ' || in_unit_code ||
    ', CHARGE: ' || in_charge_code);
END my_procedure;
```

And i make the call like this:

```
BEGIN
    my_procedure('0000000004','CHARGE01','ROLECODE01');
    my_procedure('0000000003','CHARGE02','ROLECODE01');
    my_procedure('0000000002','CHARGE00','ROLECODE03');
    my_procedure('0000000001','CHARGE00','ROLECODE03');
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure SQL solution:

```
insert into your_table t
select unit_code, charge_code, 'NEWROL'
from 
    ( select unit_code, charge_code from your_table
      where (unit_code = '0101010001' and charge_code = 5023409)
      or    (unit_code = '0102010002' and charge_code = 4023409)
      minus
      select unit_code, charge_code from your_table
      where  role_code = 'NEWROL' )
/
```

The sub-query returns the set of `(unit_code, charge_code)` which don't have a `role_code='NEWROL'`.  You can tweak the upper WHERE clause to use PL/SQL parameters if you really need a stored procedure.

---

Here is one solution for proceduralizing this query.  It employs a SQL type for passing the target `(unit_code, charge_code)` pairs:

```
create or replace type unit_charge_t as object
    (unit_code varchar2(10), charge_code number);
/
create or replace type unit_charge_nt as table of unit_charge_t;
/
```

This is a bare-bones proof of concept.  You'll need to add logging, exception handling, etc.

```
create or replace procedure ins_your_table
    (p_recs in unit_charge_nt
     , p_new_role in your_table.role_code%type := 'NEWROL')
as
begin
    insert into your_table t
    select unit_code, charge_code, 'NEWROL'
    from 
        ( select unit_code, charge_code from your_table
          where (unit_code, charge_code) in (select * from table(p_recs))
    minus
    select unit_code, charge_code from your_table
    where  role_code = 'NEWROL' );
    dbms_output.put_line('inserted records = '||sql%rowcount);
end ins_your_table;
/
```

Example invocation:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare 
  2      tgt_rows unit_charge_nt  
  3          := unit_charge_nt ( unit_charge_t('0101010001', 5023409)
  4                              , unit_charge_t('0102010002', 4023409) );
  5  begin
  6      ins_your_table(tgt_rows);   
  7  end;
  8  /
inserted records = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The biggest challenge remains getting the target keys from a document into the database.  Personally I would choose a programmer's text editor such as NotePad++.  That would make it a cinch to translate a list of values into those Type assignments using regex search'n'replace.

```
search: ([0-9]+)\t([0-9]+)
replace: unit_charge_t\('\1', \z\)
```

An alternative interface would be to use an external table, changing the `.docx` into a `.csv` file.

There are any number of possible solutions; which is the most suitable will depend on the particularities of your situation.

Comment: Thats a good idea, but in this way i have to put 90 where conditions? Do you know a procedure when you run take the values ​​of the units and functions that I define? @APC

Comment: @spikeTJ - I did ask you how you were storing these values but you didn't give an actual answer.  So I'm not sure what you're expecting me to suggest.  If this is a one-off exercise you could just clone'n'edit the WHERE clause ninety times.  If you want this to be reusable you need to provide more details.

Comment: Yes, i wanna this to be reusable. I have a list of `unit_code` and respective `code_charge` to which they must insert the `NEWROL`. I'm trying to perform a procedure to insert `ROLE` for the corresponding `UNIT_CODE, CHARGE_CODE`. Sorry if i didnt explain well @APC.

Comment: Clearly I'm not explaining myself very well.  You have a list.  You want to perform a check and update for each entry in that list.  But what format is that list? Are the entries *on that list* stored in the database somehow or are they outside the database (in a spreadsheet, email, your head)?  And by reusable I mean will you need to repeat this exercise sometime in the future for a different list of (UNIT_CODE, CHARGE_CODE) pairs?

Comment: Ok, i have the list in a .docx file. So i wanna procedure because in that way i just to copy de `unit_code` and `charge` if im going to call a `procedure` and pass it as parameters. And Yes, maybe i have to repeat again for a different list but always using this parameters: `UNIT_CODE, CHARGE_CODE` @APC